# Jenkins Allure plugin on server using JDK 6

Tags: java, allure

I work in an environment where `JDK 7` cannot be used in Jenkins due to several security vulnerabilities. Since the plugin requires 7 in order to build, is there a way to install it within a Jenkins server utilizing `JDK 6`.

I'm trying to convince them to update to 8, but it may be futile. I feel like results are just not the same without Allure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of Allure developers. I don't think there's a simple way to run precompiled Allure binaries using Java 6. However I think we don't use any Java 7 specific features except diamond operator. So you could just search for diamonds (<>) in the code and add respective generic types so Java 6 would compile it. In order to build the plugin you also need to compile with Java 6 another library: [Allure Report Builder](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-report-builder).

So first `$ mvn clean install` report builder and then do the same thing with plugin code.